# How to use patterns to ignore certain part of an input string in lua?

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

**Background Information**

I have a csv file with lines that look like this:

```
+11231231234,13:00:00,17:00:00,1111100,12345,test.net
+11231231234,,,0000000,23456,test.net
+11231231234,18:00:00,19:00:00,1111100,09991,test.net
```

The lua pattern I have right now is this:

```
local id, start_time, end_time, asd, int, domain = line:match("(%+%d+),([%d%d:]*),([%d%d:]*),(%d*),([%d%*%#]*),(%a*.*)")
```

And its working

**Question**

How would I change this pattern so that IF the start_time / end_time values exist, I want to extract ONLY the first two sets of numbers?  So for example,  from this input:

```
+11231231234,18:00:00,19:00:00,1111100,09991,test.net
```

I would like to end up with these values:

```
start_time = 18:00
end_time = 19:00
```

instead of

```
start_time = 18:00:00
end_time = 19:00:00
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried changing this:

```
line:match("(%+%d+),([%d%d:]*),([%d%d:]*),(%d*),([%d%*%#]*),(%a*.*)")
```

to this:

```
line:match("(%+%d+),([%d%d:%d%d]*),([%d%d:%d%d]*),(%d*),([%d%*%#]*),(%a*.*)")
```

But it was a no go

**EDIT 1**

I changed the pattern to this:

```
 line:match("(%+%d+),(%d*:?%d*)[%d:]*,(%d*:?%d*)[%d:]*,(%d*),([%d%*#]*),(%S*)")
```

And in some cases, its working... but in the following scenarios, it fails:

```
  +11231231234,00:00:00,00:00:00,1111100,12345,test.net
```

So when the timestamp is zero across the board, it doesn't correctly trim the seconds.  I'm currently reviewing the code to make sure it's not a typo on my end. 
Thanks.

Comment: So you want only start and end if they exist, but nothing if they dont?

Comment: yes... and if they do exist, i need to truncate / remove the last set of ":00" from each

Comment: using `end` as a variable name should cause a script error. even if your interpreter would accept `end` as a variable name, which I somehow doubt  it is very bad practice.

Comment: @Piglet (hee hee, I like your handle!)  You're absolutely right.  I actually am using "start_time" and "end_time" in the real code... but in an effort to simplify my post here, I removed the _time part.  But rest assured, it's just in the post.  Sorry for the noise.  I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: My advice is to not try and cram everything into one Lua pattern. These are no regular expressions, so just use separate patterns to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
local id, start_time, end_time, asd, int, domain = 
   line:match("(%+%d+),(%d*:?%d*)[%d:]*,(%d*:?%d*)[%d:]*,(%d*),([%d%*#]*),(%S*)")
```

Comment: Egor, please see Edit 1 in my post.  Thanks.

Comment: It works as expected: `... 00:00  00:00 ...`.  What is your output?

Comment: I'm getting 00:00:00 00:00:00 in cases where there is no time specified...and then in other cases, when there is an hour... I get 13:00 15:00 as an example.

Comment: Can you reproduce wrong behavior on some other system, for example [here](https://eval.in/private/35b35fe10c42db)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using two Lua patterns for this. Since one can't define quantified sequences in Lua patterns there is no way to do it.

So, you may use

```
(%+%d+),(%d+:%d+):%d+,(%d+:%d+):%d+,(%d*),([%d#]*),(%a*.*)
```

to get `startime` and `endtime` in the form of *hh:mm* if they are both present, and if the pattern does not match, use your previous one.

Also note that the bracket expressions match a single character (class), so `[%d%d:]` matches the same characters - digits and `:` - as `[%d:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using `,` as the delimiter, using a function, such as:

```
function Explode(sInput)
  local x = {}
  for w in sInput:gmatch "(.-)," do
    table.insert(x, w)
  end
  return x
end
```

You'll get all 5 values in the form of a table. Now, just check whether the strings at indices `2` and `3` are not empty, and parse them as per your requirements:

```
-- Use unpack if not using lua 5.3
 local id, start_time, end_time, asd, int, domain = table.unpack( Explode(line) )
if start_time:len() > 1 then
  start_time = start_time:match "(%d+:%d+)"
end
if end_time:len() > 1 then
  end_time = end_time:match "(%d+:%d+)"
end
```